# Agrupar valores en laravel según otro valor

Tags: php, laravel, array

Holis, tengo una colección de datos que contiene, (por ejemplo, porque esto sale según las operaciones del día):

```
"id" => 53
    "articulo_id" => 23
    "almacen_id" => 1
    "transtype" => "TR"
    "comentario" => "Transferencia origen 5"
    "trans_id" => 5
    "cantidad" => -5
    "onhand" => 10
    "created_at" => "2022-10-17 09:04:17"
    "updated_at" => "2022-10-17 09:04:17"
    "articulo" => "Caja clips nro 1"

"id" => 54
    "articulo_id" => 23
    "almacen_id" => 2
    "transtype" => "TR"
    "comentario" => "Transferencia destino 5"
    "trans_id" => 5
    "cantidad" => 5
    "onhand" => 5
    "created_at" => "2022-10-17 09:04:17"
    "updated_at" => "2022-10-17 09:04:17"
    "articulo" => "Caja clips nro 1"
```

Que obtengo mediante:

```
$data = Operacion::join('articulos as a', 'a.id', 'operaciones.articulo_id')
            ->select('operaciones.*', 'a.nombre as articulo')
            ->whereBetween('operaciones.created_at', [$from, $to])
            ->when($artId > 0, function($query) use($artId){
                return $query->where('articulo_id', $artId);
            
            })
            ->get();
```

Ahora, quiero agrupar primero por `articulo_id` y luego por `almacen_id` de forma que me quede algo así en una vista, (esto iría dentro de una tabla):

```
Artículo 1
          Almacén 1
                   created_at   comentario   cantidad   onhand
                   created_at   comentario   cantidad   onhand
                   created_at   comentario   cantidad   onhand
          Almacén 2
                   created_at   comentario   cantidad   onhand
                   created_at   comentario   cantidad   onhand
```

Intenté hacerlo mediante

```
foreach ($data as $k => $operacion) {
        $operaciones[$operacion['articulo_id']][$k] = $operacion['comentario'];

    }
```

Pero a partir de eso no sé cómo traerme todo y luego agruparlo por almacén ni mostrarlo en una vista de la forma que quiero.

No sé si hay alguna otra forma de lograr esto, si podrían ayudarme, lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: ¿Que datos quieres que contenga `Operacion x`?  ¿y que es `Fecha`?

Comment: realmente debe contener ``cantidad``, ``onhand``, ``trans_id``, ``comentario``, ``transtype``. La fecha es ``created_at``

Comment: Eso de la tabla no lo veo en la pregunta. Tan solo te he dado una solucion a nivel de array que entiendo puedes recorrer en la vista supongo que para rellenar esa tabla. Lo que ya no se como ayudarte es como se recorre eso en blade, pues no lo uso (ni laravel, mi solución es array de PHP, tal como tu ibas a crear tu array pero bien hecho). He borrado mi respuesta si no te sirve. Suerte!

Comment: Acabo de recuperar mi respuesta y la he intentado completar con lo de la tabla de la vista y todo eso... mira si te sirve ahora algo mejor para hacer lo que deseas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
$articulos = [];
foreach ($data as $k => $operacion) {
    $articulos[$operacion['articulo']][$operacion['almacen_id']][] = $operacion;
}
print_r($artículos);
```

Y eso te devolverá un array más o menos así:

```
[
    "Caja clips nro 1" => [
        "1" => [["articulo_id" => 23,
                "almacen_id" => 1,
                "transtype" => "TR",
                "comentario" => "Transferencia origen 5",
                "trans_id" => 5,
                "cantidad" => -5,
                "onhand" => 10,
                "created_at" => "2022-10-17 09:04:17",
                "updated_at" => "2022-10-17 09:04:17",
                "articulo" => "Caja clips nro 1",
               ]],
        "2" => [["articulo_id" => 23
                "almacen_id" => 2
                "transtype" => "TR"
                "comentario" => "Transferencia destino 5"
                "trans_id" => 5
                "cantidad" => 5
                "onhand" => 5
                "created_at" => "2022-10-17 09:04:17"
                "updated_at" => "2022-10-17 09:04:17"
                "articulo" => "Caja clips nro 1"
                ]]
    ]
]
```

donde, si luego escribes esto:

```
$articulo = "Caja clips nro 1";
$almacen_id = "2";
echo $articulos[$articulo][$almacen_id][0]['created_at'];
```

te devolverá la fecha del primer registro de ese artículo en ese almacén.

Y así con todos los demás campos.

### Cómo generar la tabla

En cuanto a como mostrarlo en la vista en forma de tabla, pues entiendo que le debes pasar esa variable $articulos a la vista y recorrerla así:

```
<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
@foreach ($articulos as $articulo => $almacen)
    <tr><td colspan="4"><h3>Artículo {{$articulo}}</h3></td></tr>
  @foreach ($almacen as $almacen_id => $operaciones)
    <tr><td colspan="4"><h5>Almacen {{$almacen_id}}</h5></td></tr>
    @foreach ($operaciones as $index => $operacion)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$operacion['created_at']}}</td>
      <td>{{$operacion['comentario']}}</td>
      <td>{{$operacion['cantidad']}}</td>
      <td>{{$operacion['onhand']}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Como decia en los comentarios, no se laravel ni blade, pero entiendo que se pueden anidar **foreach** en blade y recorrer ese array.

Todo esto te lo digo un poco a ciegas, pues no puedo reproducir tu entorno, pero un bucle es un bucle y puedo tener fallos de sintaxis, pero de lógica no creo.

Prueba a ver si te sirve de algo tal como lo he expuesto ahora.

Comment: pero en mi vista lo que quiero es crear una tabla con toda la información, como lo ponía en la pregunta, y no son datos dinámicos, ya que serían las operaciones del día. ¿cómo puedo hacer esa parte con el array de esa forma?

Comment: Eso de la tabla no lo veo en la pregunta. Tan solo te he dado una solucion a nivel de array que entiendo puedes recorrer en la vista supongo que para rellenar esa tabla. Lo que ya no se como ayudarte es como se recorre eso en blade, pues no lo uso (ni laravel, mi solución es array de PHP, lo siento si no te sirve, borraré la respuesta pues en breve)

Comment: si yo quisiera en ``<h3>Artículo {{$articulo_id}}</h3>`` en vez de ``$articulo_id`` referenciar el nombre del artículo, que es ``articulo``, ¿es eso posible?

Comment: Si, no no, me he equivocado, por eso lo he borrado... estoy pensado :-)

Comment: Prueba con `<h3>Artículo {{$almacen[0]['articulo']}}</h3>` a ver si cuela

Comment: ahora es ``Undefined array key 0``

Comment: jolin... mmm... una pregunta... el resto te daba bien?  salia todo?

Comment: sí, el resto sirvió, ¿debería crear otra pregunta para esto?

Comment: no, dame unos minutos... seguramente si en lugar de 0 pones `"1"` funciona, pero no es optimo porque no siempre estará en el almacen 1

Comment: Si el nombre de los artículos con el mismo articulo_id no cambia **seguro** en ninguno de los almacenes entonces podría cambiar mi respuesta para conseguir lo que pides facilmente, pero ¿estamos seguros de ello?  Lo digo porque si cambia entonces se agruparan por el nombre en lugar del ID y podría generar más artículos de los que realmente hay según su articulo_id

Comment: no, el nombre siempre es el mismo, porque me lo estoy trayendo de otra tabla según el id, ¿me explico?

Comment: ok, pues voy a modificar mi respuesta, un segundo

Comment: una pregunta mas antes de ello... ¿es posible que haya artículos con distinto ID pero con el mismo nombre?

Comment: no, los nombres son únicos

Comment: vale, revisa de nuevo mi respuesta a ver si ahora si... he hecho algunos cambios (actualiza la página si no los ves)

Comment: funcionó perfecto, muchísimas gracias

Comment: Perfecto :-) Me alegro que te haya servido.  Saludos!!